# update values with history in database

Tags: database-design

I have got a next situation. In my database, I got 2 tables and one relationship between them:

**Document**
PK_Doc
FK_Employee
Text

**Employee**
PK_Employee
Name
SurName

So, when I update(delete) an existing employee the document must have the values of an employee that existed at creation time. How should I do this?

**Upd 1:**
For example: 
I am creating a new document(PK_Doc = 1) and choose in combobox Employee (Edward Norton). Then Edward Norton became Edward Harrison. So, when I open a document (PK_Doc = 1) current value of combobox with employee should be Edward Norton

Comment: Question not clear: please provide data examples to show the start and end of the scenario you describe. Note that you cannot delete a row from employee if Document has a FK to it.

Comment: Add Upd 1. Is it full scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an Employee_History table containing at least the following columns

PK_Employee_History_Id
Employee_Id (not a constraint)
Name
Surname
ValidFrom (Date)

On Employee creation/update/delete scenarios you create a new record in Employee_History - I would use a SQL trigger for this.

Point your Document at the immutable Employee_History table record rather than the mutable Employee record.

Comment: I think it's good working way. But I will try to solve my problem without adding a new table of history. I think I can add 2 columns in Employee: Guid and RowDate. And in Documents table FK to Guid. So when edit an Employee - I will add a new row with same Guid.

Comment: I hope this application is for personal use only - I would never sanction this approach in any commercial setting! You'll essentially have a table which looks like it contains Employees, containing EmployeeHistory records, and an Id which looks like it matches an Employee in reality just being a pointer to some arbritary point in the Employee's History, with the real ID being the GUID you've added. Very confusing and awkward schema design.

Comment: Referencing Denis's Link I think that what you are suggesting is probably Type 2 but you need to be clear with your names to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you need to deal with a few [slowly changing dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension). Bony suggested type 4, but you've other options. See also [bi-temporal databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database) in case you need a precise audit-trail.

Comment: thanks for a very usefull link. I hope, that my english is enought to understand this wiki page fast